# Android manually adding Toolbar vs default Theme Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In all the examples I see that people remove the default ActionBar with

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and then re-add it with

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Why is this better than just using the default ActionBar that comes with the theme? Since doing it this way I have to manually add it in every Activity in my application while using the default it gets added on its own ? Plus using the Toolbar from the Theme I can now reduce my main_activity_layout.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"/>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since `Toolbar`s are regular `View`s, they're easier to modify and tailor to one's needs. If the provided `ActionBar` does everything you need, you can just use that.

Comment: well I can access the "default" toolbar with .getActionBar() right ? So once I have this I can do whatever I like. There has to be a reason why people do this ...

Comment: Honestly, the reason most people do it is because they blindly copy code from examples they see online. As I said, though, a `Toolbar` is easier to modify, and a lot of things to do with the `ActionBar` pattern have been deprecated.

Comment: With you second XML you've changed the behaviour of your layout. The `CoordinatorLayout` will take care to translate the `Toolbar` of the screen as soon as you scroll vertically. This won't be possible with the default `ActionBar`.

Comment: I don't scroll vertically nowhere. I only scroll sideways with the ViewPager. Plus this is just an example I was looking at. The main point behind it is to show how people remove the ActionBar with the ** windowActionBar** and **windowNoTitle** Theme properties, but manually add it later in the layout.xml and in java code. I am looking for the reason behind this and why is preferable.

Comment: If you don't need it, don't use it. Any speculation as to why someone would use it when it's not needed is going to be opinion-based, and therefore unsuitable for SO. The example you pasted is using a `CoordinatorLayout`, so apparently that user wants to take advantage of functionalities offered by that particular View, which, as mentioned by reVerse, they wouldn't be able to do using a pre-defined `ActionBar`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a must to use **ToolBar** but It's better to use It if you want your app to follow material design guidelines.And also

- If You want to add a widget to it, You can do this easily as you place items in it as you do in any other layout.
- You can place it any where in your layout.
- you can create as many toolbars as you like.

There are actually more reasons I haven't mentioned.